# How to connect to my private ethereum network using web3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, connections

I have setup my own private eth network. I wanted to connect to this. So first I have run

```
geth --datadir ./tolotolo --networkid 1115 --port 30304 console 2>>myEth.log
```

It generated geth.ipc file. Then I do

```
geth --ipcpath tolotolo/geth.ipc --networkid 1167 --port="56789"
```

Then in my node js I have installed web3 then I tried to connect

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3("ws://192.168.1.99:56789");
web3.eth.net.isListening()
    .then(() => console.log('is connected'))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

It produced output

```
Error: connection not open on send()
    at Object.ConnectionError (C:\Users\karthik.KT\workspace\tolotolo\server\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:69:23)
    at Object.ConnectionNotOpenError (C:\Users\karthik.KT\workspace\tolotolo\server\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:48:21)
    at C:\Users\karthik.KT\workspace\tolotolo\server\node_modules\web3-providers-ws\src\index.js:181:37
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebsocketProvider._onClose (C:\Users\karthik.KT\workspace\tolotolo\server\node_modules\web3-providers-ws\src\index.js:180:27)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (C:\Users\karthik.KT\workspace\tolotolo\server\node_modules\yaeti\lib\EventTarget.js:115:12)
    at W3CWebSocket.onConnectFailed (C:\Users\karthik.KT\workspace\tolotolo\server\node_modules\@web3-js\websocket\lib\W3CWebSocket.js:219:14)
    at WebSocketClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\karthik.KT\workspace\tolotolo\server\node_modules\@web3-js\websocket\lib\W3CWebSocket.js:59:25)
    at WebSocketClient.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at ClientRequest.handleRequestError (C:\Users\karthik.KT\workspace\tolotolo\server\node_modules\@web3-js\websocket\lib\WebSocketClient.js:227:14)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:440:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 1006,
  reason: 'connection failed'
}
```

What is the best way to connect to my private network using web3? Thank you.web3

Comment: Try `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://192.168.1.99:56789"));`

Comment: Http provider works but I want to connect via ipc since it is more secure

Comment: You are running a recent version of web3 right? Cause I remember there being a bug with websockets

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works with this code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://192.168.1.99:56789")
var web3 = new Web3(provider);
web3.eth.net.isListening()
    .then(() => console.log('is connected'))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

You should probably also make sure that there is no firewall issue